# Show macro expansions in GNU Assembler - AS - listing. Preprocess only?

Tags: assembly, macros, preprocessor, gnu-assembler

I can't seem to find any command switch to show me the expansions of my macro definitions.

Is there a way to do this with the GNU Assembler?

For example, if I have a macro like this:

```
.macro MACROA a
    mov \a,%rax
.endm

MACROA $10
```

I'd like to see the expansions of this like so:

```
; MACROA $10
mov $10, %rax
```

I vaguely remember seeing this but don't know where anymore.

I tried the `-a` switch but it doesn't generate expansions, only opcodes are printed next to the macro

```
> as x.s -a
GAS LISTING x.s             page 1


   1                
   2                
   3                .text
   4                
   5                .macro MACROA a
   6                    mov \a, %rax
   7                .endm
   8                
   9                _start:
  10 0000 48C7C00A      MACROA $10
  10      000000

GAS LISTING x.s             page 2


DEFINED SYMBOLS
                 x.s:9      .text:0000000000000000 _start

NO UNDEFINED SYMBOLS
```

Comment: The `as` man page mentions "`-am` - include macro expansions", which presumably would do what you want.

Comment: presumably yes but I get no output from it

Comment: Ok so the answer is to use `-alm` or `-alhsm` that does the trick. using just `-am` generates nothing. @PeterCordes thanks for the help, put your comment as an answer so i can accept it. EDIT:(also `-a -am` also works)

Comment: I was just about to post the same thing! How odd that `-am` produces nothing. Is this a bug?

Comment: I get output with `-a -am` after fixing the typo in your [mcve] (MACRO instead of MACROA), so you're actually using the macro you define.  It seems `-am` doesn't imply listing, it just sets an option that's relevant if you are using listings. IDK if that's intended.

Comment: Yeah I also noticed that `-a -am` works. But i don't see that mentioned in the man pages. One would think just `-am` suffices

Comment: Oh yeah, the wording in the man page does imply that `-am` alone should turn on listings, so I think that is a bug.  Happens with Binutils 2.36.1 on my system.

Comment: @PeterCordes Alright, can you put your comments as an answer so that I can mark this solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`as -a -am`  enables listings with macro expansion.

```
...
   5                    MACROA 10
   5 0000 488B0425      >  mov 10,%rax
   5      0A000000 
       # load from absolute address 10, not mov $10, %rax.
       # That's why as -Os doesn't optimize it to a 5-byte mov to eax
...
```

The [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/as.1.html) implies that `-am` alone would turn on listings, as well as set the listing style to include macro expansion.  But in current versions of GAS (e.g. Binutils 2.36.1 on my system), that is not the case.  A separate listing option like bare `-a` is necessary to actually turn on listings.

This is a bug in GAS's option parsing; feel free to report it.  I think they use https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/

Comment: I will once I am able to make an account. But for now it seems account creation is restricted